# array_walk--> numerical array becomes words

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm using the next thing:

```
<?php
$string='JUD. NEAMT, SAT ROMEDC ALEXANDRE COM. COMENKA, STR. EXAMMS RANTEM, NR.6';
$result=preg_split("/(?:JUD.\s*|\s*SAT\s*|\s*COM\.\s*|\s*STR.\s*|\s*SECTOR\s*|\s*B-DUL\s*|\s*NR\.\s*|\s*ET.\s*|\s*MUN\.\s*|\s*BL.\s*|\s*SC\.\s*|\s*AP\.\s*)/", $string);

array_walk($result,function($value,$key) use (&$result){
    if(stristr($value, ","))
    {
        $result[$key]=explode(",", $value)[0];
    }
});
print_r(array_filter($result));
```

the output would be:

```
    Array
(
    [1] => NEAMT
    [2] => ROMEDC ALEXANDRE
    [3] => COMENKA
    [4] => EXAMMS RANTEM
    [5] => 6
)
```

The main problem is that $string is different each time and can contain different parameters like 'SAT' could simply not appear in another string because is replaced by 'SECTOR'.

All these are localization words like House number('NR.') or Town name('JUD').

What I want is to convert the above array into something like this:

```
       Array
(
    ['JUD'] => NEAMT
    ['SAT'] => ROMEDC ALEXANDRE
    ['COM'] => COMENKA
    ['STR'] => EXAMMS RANTEM
    ['NR'] => 6
)
```

I hope you got the idea:

I'm getting from a string 'address' different parameters like apartment number , building number and so on (it depends each time on the customer-- he might be living at a house so there is no apartment number) so having words instead of numbers in the array would help me output the info in different columns.

Any idea is welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string='JUD. NEAMT, SAT ROMEDC ALEXANDRE COM. COMENKA, STR. EXAMMS RANTEM, NR.6';

//fix missing commas
$string = preg_replace('#([A-Z]+) ([A-Z]+\.)#',"$1, $2",$string);
//a trick to fix non space on `NR.6`
$string = str_replace(['.','  '],['. ',' '],$string);
//get the part seperated by comma, trim to remove spaces
$ex = array_map('trim',explode(',',$string));
//iterate over it
foreach($ex as $e){
   //explode the part by space
   $new = array_map('trim',explode(' ',$e));
   //take the first part as key, remove spaces and dot
   $key = trim(array_shift($new),' . ');
   //collect via key and implode rest with a space
   $coll[$key]=implode(' ',$new);
}
//done
print_r($coll);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
   [JUD] => NEAMT
   [SAT] => ROMEDC ALEXANDRE
   [COM] => COMENKA
   [STR] => EXAMMS RANTEM
   [NR] => 6
)
```

a fast lane  to rome...

Comment: Your code almost works. I'm experiencing some problems here: https://eval.in/780354  . COM. Should be another array value with the value=COMENKA . Same with NR. -> 6

Comment: @an4rei This is more simple than your code, so update it to your needs. It is har to detected right thing in the string. Rules i have in mind: 1. all entries must be seperated by comma. 2. The first part of a substring can be used as key.  If the rules are wrong make new and code the logic. But keep it simple :-) `NR.6` is fixed, `COM.` needs a comme like `,  COM.`

Comment: Thanks alot for all this . If I am not able to modify the string in any way. How could I add a comma before 'COM.'?

Comment: @an4rei updated :-) More info only if you check my answer as right ;-)

Comment: You're simply amazing. Marked answer as right. I'm very curious on how that preg_replace works like that.

Comment: @an4rei Always nice to help .-)